# Issue In Firebase Custom Authentication And Service Account

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, service-accounts

Ok, so first of all I am not very much an expert in both java or android, in fact I am just beginner. So if anything sounds silly or irritating pardon me, I am on the verge of being blocked from asking any questions.

So, my issue is that while authenticating my server with firebase, I am facing some trouble while setting service account and creating custom token.

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup
>
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

I am taking help from here and following these steps, and this is what i have done.

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
  .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
  .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            .createCustomToken(uid)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String customToken) 
    {
        // Send token back to client
    }
});
```

But I am getting very unusual errors, i.e.

1) On service account - The method `setCredential(FirebaseCredential)` is undefined for the type `FirebaseOptions.Builder`

Now I've read that setserviceaccount is deprecated, but when i am using it, its not giving me any error

2) On Creating Custom Token - The method `addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>(){})` is undefined for the type String

It is another method error, and also I don't know how to send the token back to client. I couldn't find any example that how should i approach it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Any example that how others send there token to client, would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so finally i have solved the issue,the issue was that in my pom.xml I was also using (Firebase Server SDK Library » 3.0.3)maven repository. And thats why there were method issues.